# Python script to extract decimal values from a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file with float values and string
eg :

```
50.0 length  
15.5 diameter  
12.45 width
```

in each line in the text file.

How to get only the float value for each line?

expect output is a list with only the float values    [50.0, 15.5, 12.45]

Comment: Have you tried using Regular Expressions to solve your issue?

Comment: @user3609297 Do your homework. Or show us at least something you have tried.

Comment: Yeah, we're going to need more information than that. Things like your input, expected output and what you have tried so far are needed.

Answer (score 3):

From the information you have given, I would do:

```
with open(your_text_file_name) as f:
    values = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in f if line]
```

Comment: Best answer I can imagine from that question. +1

Comment: I try this code ,but i got an error list index out of range

Comment: @user3609297 The only way that could happen from the code I posted would be that some of the lines in the file were blank. Otherwise it is being caused by something else in the file.

Comment: @user3609297 I have modified the code so it ignores empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways to do this. Without knowing your expected input, let me throw down a couple options for you:

- Regular expressions. `\d` matches a digit. `[0123459789.]` matches every digit and the decimal point. Pull them all out, operate on them.
- String manipulation. Your example shows `1234.56 wordword`. If that follows throughout your input, split your string on the space and `float` the first element.

Comment: sorry , I am new to python script ,I tried by searching in internet but I could able to extract the float value ,Each line in a text file has a float value at the beginning followed by a string (Eg: 12.25  length) like this I have many lines , can you please provide me the python code to exact only the float value from each line of the text file

Comment: @user3609297 sounds like Alex's answer may be best then, if every single line is formatted exactly the same.

Comment: I tryed It , but the error is Index out of range , I made some changes in the code , but I couldnt able to solve it ..

Comment: @user3609297 you might have blank lines in your input file? I don't think that would cause that but I'm not sure what else would do it either. Try `[float(line.split()[0]) for line in f if line]` to filter out empty lines.